# Как избавиться от разрывов кадров(tearing)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, xorg

Тиринг замучал, перепробовал уже все что нарыл в интернете - ничто не помогает. Но иногда после обновления системы через apt upgrade(когда обновляется ядро) тиринг пропадает полностью, все работает, и т.д., но включается secure boot - я пробовал включить его вручную и делать `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-375` - тиринг не исчезает. Пробовал на разных версиях ядра - везде тиринг остается, но на некоторых версиях(4.7, 4.8, 4.9,..) становится только хуже, причем еще на этапе установки. В общем, прикладываю все логи, что смог найти, подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону гуглить.

ОС - Ubuntu 16.04.2, ядро 4.12.0(поставил вручную сразу после установки оси, на ядре 4.8 экран вообще мерцал), драйвер nvidia-375

P.S. в настройках nvidia нет ни намека на vsync, изменение настроек в CompizConfig Settings Manager на ситуацию не влияет, изменение /etc/X11/Xorg.conf не помогает(при перезапуске файл затирается дефолтным)

[/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QS0ktT0ZzUzZWZ2M)

[/var/log/kern.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QWVZrT2NlenlTVEk)

[/var/log/dmesg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QRFhmaVhLM056SzQ)

[/var/log/gpu-manager.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QWHdZWXZ0VmpOVEU)

[/var/log/syslog](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5Qa2F5czJRbUVycjg)

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QR0tRWXBvdDdEWTg)

[/etc/issue](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QN3BZa0lPR2NMeEk)

[lshw](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QNTMya05tVGhIUGM)

Comment: а где именно у вас появляется разрыв кадров?

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov перетаскивание окон, видео. в играх не тестил

Comment: Еще если подключить дополнительный монитор, он будет "рваться" по диагонали(от правого верхнего угла примерно до середины экрана)

Comment: А вариант того, что это железо виновато, не рассматривался? Тестировались ли другие линуксы или альтернативные оси?

Comment: @KoVadim  на винде проблем нет, и в описании я написал что проблема на линуксе иногда исчезает после автоматического обновления

Answer (score 3):

Знаете, в Xorg тиринг был всегда. **Из-за его архитектуры.** Изначально весь рендер пишется в буферы, а иной поток читает этот буфер и выводит на экран.

Я эту проблему вечно замечал в firefox. В последнее время тиринг куда-то пропал, стоит новенький **Archlinux**.

**Wayland vs Xorg.**

В новом граф. менеджере Wayland, который вскоре превзойдет Xorg, тиринга вообще быть не может. Из-за своей программной части.

*Пока полностью Wayland работает лишь в Gnome оболочке. KDE то работает, то не. С обновлениями его не понять.*

**Nvidia.** Как я помню он генит свой Xorg.conf, правьте.

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

И добавить строчку

```
Option  "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

**Nvidia 2.**

```
 nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

**Nvidia 3.**

```
 nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

**AMD.** Catalyst Control Center -> display ->  «Tear Free Desktop mode».

**Intel.** Иногда рывки видео происходят из-за метода ускорения **SNA**. Чтобы исправить это, включите опцию "Tearfree" в драйвере.

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

**KDE.** Может помочь, но мне оно не помогало:)

[image: Vsync]

Метод от KDE, VSync.

**Автоматическое:** В зависимости от затрат включать ли борьбу с тирингом.

**При минимуме затрат:** Работает только с полноэкранными приложениями. Представьте что вы включили Youtube на весь экран, kde включит борьбу с тирингом.
Надеюсь что-то поможет.

***Не проверено.*** Не доходили руки проверить.

`sudo nano /etc/environment  # добавь переменную`

```
CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling
```

**Комментарий.** *Я повторюсь, юзаю Archlinux, Xorg, Intel, последние дрова и тиринга больше нет, хотя раньше я его очень часто видел...*

***Дополнение.*** Только заметил, ядро ***4.12.0*** зачем такие ядра. Знаете в Archlinux самые последние пакеты и версии ядер. Сейчас у меня стоит ***4.11.8-1-zen***

***Дополнение 2.*** Если ваш Xorg.conf затирается то юзайте `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` там опишите доп файлик.

Comment: `nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"` уже пробовал - не помогает. Такое ядро потому что на некоторых других становится только хуже, вот я и взял тупо самое последнее. Насчет Wayland тоже думал, но боюсь ставить его замучаюсь, поэтому жду когда в убунте из коробки будет гном. Не подскажете в каком виде должны быть файлы в xorg.conf.d?

Comment: `CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling` тоже не дало видимых изменений

Comment: В каком виде /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/? В коде посмотрите.  Раздел Intel. Там описано именно как пользоватся xorg.conf.d

Comment: Wayland в убунте не скоро появится... На гноме wayland у меня отлично крутился, а сним и firefox, wine.

Comment: Вот еще пример как пользоватся xorg.conf.d http://linuxru.org/tips/41

Comment: Увы, ни один из способов не помог, похоже придется прикручивать гнома

Comment: Тут дело может быть и в драйверах. Еслибы вы попробовали дистрибутив например Manjaro как ситуация там

Comment: Бо у меня тиренга уже нету. а раньше я всегда его на всех устройствах видел. Почему manjaro, в ней как и в арче софт новый, может и у вас проблема исчезнет сама сабой

Comment: поставил manjaro, тиринг сильно уменьшился, но в видео в верхней части экрана все еще рвутся кадры.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62327/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 0):

Вы говорите, что в настройках нет ни намёка на vsync, разве у вас нет такого:

[image: скриншот]

Хотя вам это скорее всего не поможет, но проверьте. Я лично с этой проблемой тоже намучился. Пробовал различные дистрибутивы в сочетании с различными композитными менеджерами. Кое-где эта проблема решалась, например, в связке xubuntu+compton тиринг пропадал, но появлялась другая проблема - compton вызывал утечки памяти и жуткие лаги на моей машине. В итоге (лично у меня) проблема решилась переходом на третий гном. На удивление, в нём из коробки никакого тиринга! Плюс он поставляется с модным нынче wayland'ом, в котором эта проблема тоже должна быть решена, но я не знаю, на моей gtx465 он почему-то не фурычит.

Comment: Увы, почти никаких настроек там вообще нет https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zSHtabJF5QN3hueV82aHFqOUE